# Push Notification due to an event in a HomeKit accessory

Tags: ios, push-notification, homekit

I want my app to be aware of events triggered by HomeKit accessories ([HMAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit/hmaccessory)). Such that, when my HomeKit powered motion detector detects motion, my app gets to know about this somehow (preferably via a push notification). The preinstalled Home app seems to have this feature. Is there a way I can get this done using the HomeKit framework?

The nearest I found was this on [HMCharacteristic](https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit/hmcharacteristic):

```
func enableNotification(Bool, completionHandler: (Error?) -> Void)
```

But this doesn't result in a Push Notification and delivers updates via a delegate callback (and works only when app is foregrounded).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have to agree with Jeff Z. Not possible to do directly.

Accessory Events that are then "published" as push notifications, from my investigations, appear to be a feature of the Home App from Apple when it is setup in "Home Hub" mode on an iPad, AppleTV and soon to be HomePods. It only is a available for a short list of accessory type like doors, locks and a few others.  (I'm still searching for the definitively list in the Apple Docs) These Notifications are directed to the Home App and would not be available to another app.

If this is for your own personal use, you could setup a custom Accessory as a service that sends Push Notifications when triggered by Home Automation.

There is a Javascript/Node.js project [homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge) that implements the Home Accessory Protocol (HAP) and allows you to standup a customisable HAP service in your home network.

The general approach would be:

1. Install homebrige server on you home network.  Either on a
   computer that is always on or get a Rasberry Pi dedicated for this
   purpose.
2. Install the [homebridge-pushed-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/homebridge-pushed-notification) plugin
   and configure it to user your GetPushed app.
3. Establish an Automation in your Home App that when the event is received from your off-the-shelf Accessory, initiate the Push Notification you setup in 2.

This sends a notification to the GetPushed app.  But the general outline could work for other push services such as Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: a noob question here Say a accessory has all its commands executed via Azure cloud. Can I remotely invoke Azure API through HomeKit delegates in my own app or in Home app, and in turn those APIs call the HUB or Pi ?  and also  can I remotely invoke HomeKit devices without iCloud?

Comment: @KhanXc You should start with a fresh question to get the maximum exposure and increase the likelihood of getting a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have wanted to do this too but I don’t think there is a way to do it.